# Is it possible to repent from shirk if I forgot what exactly I did?

Tags: sharia, shirk, tawba, kufr, jahannam

Basically I was just repenting to Allah for all the things I did and I also wanted to repent for something really bad, but just some seconds later I forgot what exactly it was. Now I’m scared & worried because I think it was something really bad that I did but I can’t remember what. Can I still repent even if I don’t remember what my sin was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

pray the 5th Kalima (some call it the 6th one):

Allaa-humma Inneee A’udhu-bika Min An Ushrika Bika Shay-awn Wa-ana A’lamu Bihee Wa- astaghfiruka Limaa Laaa A’lamu Bihee Tubtu ‘Anhu Wata-barraatu Mina-l Kufri Wash-shirki Wal-kidhbi Wal-gheebati Wal-bid’ati Wan-nameemati Wal-fawahishi Wal-buhtaani Wal-m’aasi Kulli-haa Wa-Aslamtu Wa-aqoolu Laaa Ilaaha Illa-llaahu Muhammadu-r Rasoolu-llah.

O Allah! I seek refuge in You from that I should ascribe any partner with You knowingly. **I seek Your forgiveness for the sin of which I have no knowledge.** I repent from it. And becoming disgusted of disbelief and idolatry, lying and backbiting, innovation and slander, lewdness and abomination and all other acts of disobedience, I submit to Your will. I believe and I declare that there is none worthy of worship except Allah and Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah.

Allah has revealed 2 verses about forgiveness:

1. Say (on My behalf), “O servants of Mine who have acted recklessly against their own selves, do not despair of Allah’s mercy. **Surely, Allah will forgive all sins**. Surely, He is the One who is the Most-Forgiving, the Very-Merciful. (quran 39:53)

this verse indicates that Allah forgives all sins. this applies to those people who commit a sin in this world, and then seek forgiveness from Allah, and are forgiven. even if a person commits shirk, if he asks Allah sincerely for forgiveness, Allah can forgive him.

2. Indeed, Allah does not forgive associating others with Him, but forgives anything else of whoever He wills. And whoever associates others with Allah has indeed committed a grave sin. (Quran 4:48)

this refers to a the person who has died. whatever sins he has committed, even if he doesnt repent, if Allah wants, he can forgive it. the ONLY exception is shirk - if someone dies disbelieving in the oneness of Allah, he will not be forgiven and will be in Hell forever.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome. May Allah grant you peace and remove your worry.

Comment: just one more question: does this really go for ALL sins? I said the 5th Kalima and renewed my shahada but I’m still a little worried that I might still be a disbeliever